# How does a method pass an argument to a handler?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Say I have the following code:

```
var watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(displayLocation, displayError);
```

There is a method, `watchPosition`, that repeatedly calls one of the two handlers, either `displayLocation` or `displayError`.

My success handler, `displayLocation`, accepts a parameter, that is supplied by the method `watchPosition`.

I'm unable to understand how the method is passing an argument to the handler. I know that functions are treated as values. How can I replicate this in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way as you pass it to any other function.

You specify the variable referencing the function want to call, then you put `(` and `)` with the arguments between them.

```
function watchPosition(aFunction, anotherFunction) {
    if (all_is_good) {
        aFunction(1);
    } else {
        anotherFunction(2);
    }
}

var all_is_good = true;

function handler(arg) { console.log(arg); }

watchPosition(handler, handler);
```

Comment: Thanks - you're passing a function (it is treated as a value) and when you pass and call it within `watchPosition` then you're calling the `handler` function right?

Comment: Functions are values, just like any other JavaScript data type. And yes.